# All of divisors of $m$ in $b-$base representation have all of $0, 1, 2, ..., b-1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

For $b \ge 2$, prove that there exist a positive integer $m$ such that all of its divisors other than $1$ have $b-$base representation that uses all $0, 1, 2, ..., b-1$.

Comment: No $a\ge 2$ satisfy $a\mid 1$, so $1$ is an example of such $m$.

Comment: How about this? For any given $b>1$ there exist $m$ such that all of its divisors other than $1$ have $b-$base representation that uses all digits? I think this makes sense! And must be the right question to ask!

Comment: This question at least is no longer obvious.  We can make the simplification that we are searching specifically for prime $m$ since any composite such $m$ would necessarily have prime factors which would also satisfy the conditions.

Comment: Does every divisor have to use each digit exactly once, or can we have multiplicity?

Comment: In the second case: put all the digits $1,2\ldots,b-1$ in a number $k$ such that the last digit of $k$ is a $1$. Now, $\gcd(b,k)=1$, so there are infinitely many $n$ with $n\cdot b^b+k$ prime. Take any one of these and this will be $m$